# Understanding Intersections of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

<s>It seems as though the common definition for the "intersection of $\sigma-$algebras $\mathcal{E}_1, \mathcal{E}_2, \ldots$" (potentially uncountable) is the smallest $\sigma-$algebra containing every $\mathcal{E}_j$.  By this definition, it is easy to show that the intersection is also a $\sigma$-algebra, for example to show complements, if $A \in \cap_{j=1}^\infty \mathcal{E}_j$, then it is in each $\mathcal{E}_j$, which are $\sigma-$algebras, so $A^C \in \mathcal{E}_j$ for all $j$, and hence in $\cap_{j=1}^\infty \mathcal{E}_j$.</s>

However, I seem to recall seeing it also defined as (for simplicity, the two $\sigma-$algebra case):
$$ \mathcal{E}_1 \cap \mathcal{E}_2 = \{A_1 \cap A_2: A_1 \in \mathcal{E}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{E}_2\}.$$

1. Are these two definitions equivalent?
2. If so, then I have trouble proving from first principles that the latter is contained in $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$ (which follows trivially if we use the first definition).  In particular, if we let $A \in \mathcal{E}_1 \cap \mathcal{E}_2$, then $A = A_1 \cap A_2,$ where $A_1 \in \mathcal{E}_1$ and $A_2 \in \mathcal{E}_2$.  However, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are arbitrary members of their respective $\sigma-$algebras, so how would we go about showing $A \in \mathcal{E}_1$ when we know nothing about $A_2$?

Maybe I am having a brain fart when it comes to containment.  Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit:** In response to the comments, I definitely need to be more precise, and what I stated as the "common definition" is not correct above.  Specifically, I would like to have the definition as: if $\mathcal{E}_1, \mathcal{E}_2, \ldots,$ are each collection of sets (according to some index set $I$), then $A \in \bigcap_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i$ implies $A \in \mathcal{E}_i$ for all $i \in I$.

Then my question is: is this definition equivalent to defining
$$ \bigcap_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i = \left\{\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i : A_i \in \mathcal{E}_i \; \forall i \in I\right\}?$$

My thought is no, since if we adopt the second definition, all it means is that $A \in \bigcap_{i \in I} \mathcal{E}_i \Rightarrow A = \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$ and it is not clear (to me, anyways) how to show that $A \in \mathcal{E}_i$ for any particular $i \in I$.

Comment: Don't you mean "contained into" instead of "containing"?

Comment: No, "the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing each $E_j$" is certainly not the definition of the intersection of the $E_j$. Talking about what a definition ""seems" to be seems silly - a definition is what it is. Look up what the two definitions actually _are_ - answering questions about actual definitions seems less pointless than trying to address what it seems to you they are.

Comment: Hmm, I believed $ \mathcal{E}_1 \cap \mathcal{E}_2 = \sigma(\{A_1 \cap A_2: A_1 \in \mathcal{E}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{E}_2\})$. Having only intersections do not  guarantee that we get a sigma-field. For example take: $ \{ \emptyset, \Omega, A , A' \}$ and $ \{ \emptyset, \Omega, B, B' \}$ where $A \neq B$ nor $A \neq B' $ and $ A \cap B \neq \emptyset $. All intersections of elements would give us : $ \{ \emptyset, \Omega, A, A', B, B' , A \cap B, A \cap B', B \cap A' , B' \cap A' \}$ however $ (A \cap B )' $ is missing for example.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think you misread the question. The use of "seems" is being applied to the word "common", not "definition". Jimmy is merely indicating what he perceives as being the common definition, being cautious because unless one is an expert in an area, determining commonality is very hard.

Comment: @RghtHndSd Whatever he meant by the word "seems", the idea that that's the definition of the intersection is absurd. If he's going to ask about definitions he should get them straight first.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah, I see. You seem to feel the need to be derogatory to someone getting something wrong on a question and answer site because they didn't live up to your bar of correctness. Jimmy's question is well written and clearly thought out, regardless of the correctness of the definition. I implore you to save the type of response you gave above to someone at least more deserving, if you must make it at all.

Comment: @RghtHndSd I don't see anything derogatory about my comments here. Well written and thought out? He asks why two "definitions" are equivalent, when _neither_ is the actual definition he's seen. When someone asks a question here  they owe us the effort to get the question straight - to try to answer the question in its present form one has to first guess what the actual question _is_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks for the comments.  My initial "common definition" was incorrect.  I edited the question to be more precise.  The second is a definition that I have definitely seen.  The former, I think I mixed up with generating $\sigma-$algebras.

Comment: The revised first definition is just the ordinary intersection of  a family of sets, great. I don't believe you've seen the second definition. Look up where you think you've seen it and let us know what iit was supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, my "underlying space" is $\mathbb{R}$ throughout the following.

---

The second "definition" - which I'll call "$Cap(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}$" for clarity - is definitely **not** equivalent to the first definition.

One way to get a particularly extreme difference is due to the fact that in the second "definition," you're allowing intersections of *too many things* - $\sigma$-algebras are only guaranteed to be closed under *countable* intersections. For example, take $I=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{E}_i$ the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of Borel sets *for each $i$*. Clearly we have, using the correct definition, that $$\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{E}_i=\mathcal{B}$$ *(and we'd better: intersecting a thing with itself shouldn't change it, regardless of how many times I do that)*. But *every* set of reals is in $Cap(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}$ - that is, $Cap(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, which is a lot bigger than $\mathcal{B}$.

To see this, fix $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and for $i\in I$ let $A_i=\mathbb{R}$ if $i\in X$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{i\}$ if $i\not\in X$ (remember $I=\mathbb{R}$). Each $A_i$ is in $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{E}_i$, so $$\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=X\in Cap(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}.$$

---

It's even worse than that, though: $Cap(\mathcal{E}_i)_{i\in I}$ isn't generally closed under complements or unions! This is because complements and intersections don't commute, and this can happen even if $I$ is finite (so we get disagreement even when only two $\sigma$-algebras are involved).

---

EDIT: The above gives *examples* of what goes wrong, but David Ullrich's answer gets at the real issue here of *why* it's wrong: that intersections of **sets** and intersections of **elements** are being conflated here. The intersection of two sets of sets is not the same as the set of intersections of the elements of those sets, e.g. considering $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and $\{\{a\},\{b,c\}\}$ as our two sets-of-sets we have $$\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}\cap\{\{a\}, \{b, c\}=\{\{a\}\}$$

but $$\{\{a\}\cap \{a\}, \{a\}\cap \{b,c\}, \{a,b\}\cap \{a\}, \{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}\}=\{\{a\}, \{b\}, \emptyset\}.$$

Comment: One might get the idea from this that the uncountability of $I$ iis the problem, instead of the fact that the intersection of a family of sets has nnothing to do with the intersections of the elements of those sets. You could just say $E_1=\{\emptyset,\Bbb R\}$ and $E_2$ is the set of Lebesgue measurable sets; then $E_1\cap E_2=E_1$ but $Cap(E_1,E_2)=E_2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sure - I just wanted to go for one kind of extreme.

Comment: Whatever. "The point is that in the second 'definition,' you're allowing intersections of too many things - $\sigma$-algebras are only guaranteed to be closed under countable intersections." seems simply wrong to me; that's not the  point. Cuz if that were the point then an example where $I$ was countable would be ok.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's a good point, that was misleading of me. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Noah has given an excellent explanation of why the two definitions are not equivalent. I'm going to add a bit explaining why there's simply no reason one would ever think they were the same - the second definition simply has nothing to do with the intersection.

It was hard to give a coherent reply to the previous version of the question, since the first definition was so wrong. But in the revised version of the question you define the intersection of a family of $\sigma$-algebras to be simply  the *intersection*. Great - I'd thought you meant something else by the intersection.

The second definition deals with intersections of the *elements of* the algebras. That makes no sense - the intersection $A\cap B$ has nothing to do with $x\cap y$ for $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Think about a simple example: If $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$ then $A\cap B=\{2\}$,, right?  Now what could that possibly have to do with things like $1\cap 2$ or $2\cap 2$?

(This is why I'm certain you haven't actually seen the intersection defined as in your second supposed definition.)

**Edit:** Come to think of it, one can give an equally simple involving $\sigma$-algebras. Say $X$ is a set with more than one element. Let $E_1=\{\emptyset, X\}$ and let $E_2$ be a different $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Then $E_1\cap E_2=E_1$, but $\{A_1\cap A_2:A_i\in E_i\}=E_2$.

Comment: To clarify for the OP: the interpretation here is that $A,B$ are your $\mathcal{E}_i$s and the $x,y$ are your $A_i$s, with the point being that the intersection of two sets of sets is not the set of intersections of the elements of those sets.